# List contains exactly three of the same elements?

Tags: python, list, count, integer

This will return Boolean True if the list has three of the same integers given. It will return a Boolean False if it does not have three of the same integers. I am having trouble writing this. Does the count feature do this? Also, is importing an empty list necessary? I have this and I get the error "'int' object has no attribute 'count'". Thank you!

```
    def threeOfAKind(aList,n):
       if aList.count(n):
           return True
       else:
           return False
```

threeOfAKind([1,2,3,4,4,4],4]) should return True
I tried aList.count(n) but now I get True no matter what I call

Comment: How are you calling that method? Because based on the error, you are clearly passing `n` as an integer, which explains the error you are getting.

Comment: threeOfAKind([1,2,3,4,4,4],4])  this should return True

Comment: Put that in your question. Do you understand why you are getting your error message? Do you realize that `n` is in fact your integer `4` that you are passing in your method? You are trying to call `count` on an integer, which the message is telling you that `int` has no attribute `count`.

Comment: That makes sense, I understand that I am trying to call count on an integer, where do I go about putting the 3 at then? I get what you are saying but I'm still clueless as to what to write

Comment: OK. I want you to try to figure this out on your own :) Let me give you a hint. `aList.count(x)`. What do you think `x` should be. Read up on what list count does. You have one final thing missing in your code to check if you in fact have a three of a kind. Update your question in a few minutes if you still can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
if aList.count(n):
```

is the reason why your code is not working.

The `count` function of `list` returns the number of occurences of `n` in the list. If your arguments are [1,2,3,4,4,4] and 4, `aList.count(n)` will return 3 because 4 occurs 3 times in the list.

So the line of code above is basically the same as:

```
if 3:
```

Now 3 will get converted to a boolean value because that's what expected for an `if` condition. If you want to know 3 is converted to True or False, just try `bool(3)` in your interactive Python interpreter.

What you want is to check if `n` occures 3 times in the list, so you may need to compare the returned value of `aList.count(n)` with something? You obvisouly don't want to return True if `aList.count(n)` returns 2 or 4, do you?